# How to add new object in Kotlin SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have this preference manager

```
class JournalManager {
    lateinit var pref: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor
    lateinit var con: Context
    var PRIVATE_MODE: Int = 0

    constructor(con: Context?) {
        if (con != null) {
            this.con = con
        }
        if (con != null) {
            pref = con.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE)
        }
        editor = pref.edit()
    }

    companion object {
        val PREF_NAME: String = "Journal"
        val KEY_TEXT: String = "text"
    }

    fun createJournalSession(
        text: EditText,
    ) {
        editor.putString(KEY_TEXT, text.toString())
        editor.commit()
    }

    fun getJournalDetails(): Map<String, String>
    {
        var journal: Map<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()
        pref.getString(KEY_TEXT,null)?.let { (journal as HashMap).put(KEY_TEXT, it) }
        return journal
    }

    fun DeleteJournal() {
        editor.clear()
        editor.commit()

        var i: Intent = Intent(con, JournalActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        con.startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

And I'm looking for solution to add objects in it but my app is crashing, here is a sample of how I try to add object

```
lateinit var journalSession: JournalManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {...}

fun openDialog() {
        val dialog = MaterialDialog(this)
            .noAutoDismiss()
            .customView(R.layout.layout_new_journal)

        //set initial preferences
        dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.save_btn).setOnClickListener{
            val note = dialog.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.new_journal_input)
      

            //add to preference
            journalSession.createJournalSession(
              note
            )
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancel_btn).setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        dialog.show()
    }
```

**Any suggestion?**

## Update

Let me make it clear what I'm looking for:

1. At the beginning I do not have any data, nor shared preference in device (shared preference will create when user saves it's first journal).

2.When user adds new journal it suppose to be stored (as of sample) like this

> ```
> journal [{
>   note="this was user first note"
> }]
> ```

3. Then when next time user adds new journal, it suppose to be stored (as of sample) like this

> ```
> journal [{
>   note="this was user first note"
>   },
>   {note="this was user second note"
> }]
> ```

and so on...

`PS` So far all videos, articles anything else I've found on web was with same logic: (they've had a List and then store that list into preferences!), my case is not like that, **I do not have any list to store** my list will be created **one by one, during the time** just like any real world apps.

**Now, any idea how to make it happen, and what should I change in my code?**

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` saves primitive type data and `Srting`. For saving object like `List` you can use `GSON` library (by Google) to  convert the object into `JSON` `String`.

**1. Import Dependency:**

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

**2. Basic Usage:**

```
val studentJsonString = Gson().toJson(student)    //object -> String

val student = Gson().fromJson(studentJsonString, Student.class)    //String -> object
```

**3. For `List`:**

```
val typeToken = TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}

val students = Gson().fromJson(studentsJsonString, typeToken.getType())
```